# Alexandroff one-point compactification

Tags: general-topology

I try to get a feeling for the Alexandroff compactification. How can I imagine this one-point-compactification?

Example: $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \overline{B^3}$ with $\overline{B^3}$ the closed ball.
Why ist the one-point-compactification $(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \overline{B^3})\cup\{\infty\}$ ($\infty$ point at infinity) an open ball?

I would be pleased to hear more examples.

Thanks.

Comment: The one point compactification is not an open ball. I suggest going down one dimension as that allows an easier visualization. The Alexandroff compactification of $\Bbb R^2\setminus\bar B^2$ is a pinched sphere, $S^2$ with north and south pole identified.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Interesting answer! Thanks! Could you give another excample which illustrates the Alexandroff compactification?

Comment: It seems that the Alexandroff compactification of natural numbers is a convergent sequence, of a real line - circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find it helpful to compare with a [one point sequential compactification](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/brown-seq-comp.pdf). Recall $X$ is sequentially compact if every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence. So if $X$ is not sequentially compact, add an extra point, say $\omega$, and arrange the topology so that the sequences not convergent in $X$ converge to $\omega$. Details are in the cited paper.

I thought about this by teaching a second year course in analysis, and realised how nice was the use of sequences, something I had been snobbish about as a student! So I looked at related issues.

Comment: Although this specific question is not of my current interest, since I asked it a long time ago, your answer is nice. Thank you!